# MongoDb map-reduce exception

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have the following ***prototype***:

```
{
    "_id" : "Nwva",
    "cat" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ffee943e4b08a66fd8e84a1"),
        "slug" : "fun"
    },
    "imp" : false,
    "int" : {
        "comm" : 0,
        "fblk" : 1,
        "fbsh" : 0
    }
}
```

And the following ***map reduce*** function:

```
var mapFunction1 = function() {
    if (!this.int || (typeof this.int != 'object')) {
        this.int = {};
    }
    var lk = this.int.lk;
    var dlk = this.int.dlk;
    .....
    .....
};
```

When I have a prototype without the field **"int"**, I've got the error:

> JavaScript execution failed: map reduce failed:{  "errmsg" :
>   "exception: JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'lk' of undefined near '= this.int.lk; \t\tvar dlk =
>   this.int.dlk'  (line 5)",     "code" : 16722,     "ok" : 0 }

I have tried everything, assigned `"this.int = {};"` always and nothing.

I've tried unsuccessfully several ways to assign an empty object when this.int is undefined in order to avoid the exception.

Is this variable read-only in map function scope?

How can I resolve this?

**Additional info**

Here we have a simple test:

```
db.contenido.insert( { "_id": "Flor" });
db.contenido.find({ "_id": "Flor" } );
{ "_id" : "Flor" }

db.contenido.mapReduce(function() { var lk = this.int.lk;}, function() {}, { query :  { "_id" : "Flor" }, out : { inline : 1 },verbose: 1 });

Tue Jul 23 17:39:53.114 JavaScript execution failed: map reduce failed:{
    "errmsg" : "exception: JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'lk' of undefined near '= this.int.lk; printjsononeline( this.int' ",
    "code" : 16722,
    "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:L970

db.contenido.mapReduce(function() { if (!this.int || (typeof this.int != 'object')) {this.int = {};} var lk = this.int.lk;}, function() {}, { query :  { "_id" : "Flor" }, out : { inline : 1 },verbose: 1 });

Tue Jul 23 17:41:04.035 JavaScript execution failed: map reduce failed:{
    "errmsg" : "exception: JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'lk' of undefined near '= this.int.lk;}' ",
    "code" : 16722,
    "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:L970


db.contenido.mapReduce(function() { this.int = {}; var lk = this.int.lk;}, function() {}, { query :  { "_id" : "Flor" }, out : { inline : 1 },verbose: 1 });


Tue Jul 23 17:41:21.926 JavaScript execution failed: map reduce failed:{
    "errmsg" : "exception: JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'lk' of undefined near '= this.int.lk;}' ",
    "code" : 16722,
    "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:L970
```

Comment: maybe "this" is frozen before your function is applied...

Comment: Where are you trying to execute this code from? I just tried a simple version of what you've got and it worked.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I've added a simple test as an example. Could you set a this attribute on map function?

Comment: Have you tried to define a new variable like `var that = this;` in the beginning of your map function and do all modification on `that`?

Comment: Gotcha. My data apparently was too simple to catch the specific error you've got. You can't set data onto the document (represented by `this`). You'll need to just copy the data